# Sort array by parent relationship

Tags: javascript, sorting

I want to sort an array by parent relationship. Basically, i want all records in an order where the parent index must always be above the child's index. 
A parent can only be linked once, so the only issue here is that a child can be a parent.
The data source will look like:

```
[{
            id: 1,
            parentId: null
        }, {
            id: 2,
            parentId: 4
        }, {
            id: 3,
            parentId: null
        }, {
            id: 4,
            parentId: 3
        }, {
            id: 5,
            parentId: 2
        }]
```

One method I tried was a while to check if the record's parent is below the current index and move up accordingly, but that just loops endlessly and becomes very inefficient.

```
function hasParentAbove(collection, rec) {
    if (rec.parentId === null) {
        return true;
    };

    let parentIndex = collection.map(s => s.id).indexOf(rec.parentId);
    let recIndex = collection.map(s => s.id).indexOf(rec.id);
    let hasParentBelow = parentIndex > recIndex;
    //return hasParentBelow;
    console.log('Has Parent Below', hasParentBelow)
    return hasParentBelow;
}

function orderByDependant(records) {
    Array.prototype.move = function (from, to) {
        this.splice(to, 0, this.splice(from, 1)[0]);
    };

    //order to add null first
    records = records.sort(function (a, b) { return a.parentId - b.parentId });


    //if the record has parent below, move down in the list
    let index;
    do {
        records.forEach(rec => {
            if (!hasParentAbove(records, rec)) {
                index = records.indexOf(rec); //find index in collection
                records.move(index, index--); //shift down one
                console.log('move');
            };
        });
    } while (records.some(rec => !hasParentAbove(records, rec)));

    return records;
}
```

The following jasmine test case might simplify the functionality needed.

```
    it('Check method', () => {

       let res = YourSorter
        expect(res[0].id).toBe(1);
        expect(res[1].id).toBe(3);
        expect(res[2].id).toBe(4);
        expect(res[3].id).toBe(2);
        expect(res[4].id).toBe(5);

    });
```

Comment: Also note its ECMA 6 friendly,

Answer (score 0):

came out a little bit silly:) i guess it's better use bubble sort

```js
var arr = [{
    "id": 2,
    "parentId": 4
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "parentId": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "parentId": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "parentId": null
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "parentId": null
  }
];
arr.sort(function(A, B) {
  var aParent = A.parentId * 1;
  var bParent = B.parentId * 1;
  var a = A.id * 1;
  var b = B.id * 1;

  if (aParent || bParent) {
    return aParent - bParent;
  } else {
    return a - b
  }

});
arr.sort(function(A, B) {
  var aParent = A.parentId * 1;
  var bParent = B.parentId * 1;
  var a = A.id * 1;
  var b = B.id * 1;

  if (aParent || bParent) {
    if (aParent == b) return 1;
    else return -1;
  }
});
arr.sort(function(A, B) {
  var aParent = A.parentId * 1;
  var bParent = B.parentId * 1;
  var a = A.id * 1;
  var b = B.id * 1;

  if (aParent || bParent) {
    if (aParent == b) return 1;
    else return -1;
  }
  return a - b;
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: so in this case i want the parent to be listed before the child for each record. 
so in a case where a child is a parent as well, i want that to be listed before its child. (A parent can only be linked once). its not really about sorting via id, but instead by the relationship to the parent.

Comment: Updated question to include jasmine to illustrate a valid result.

Comment: yeah, i saw that, trying to make it atm, the task is interesting

Comment: i updated my answer, but its looks `hacky` to me...i think bubble sort will do it better, but i'm not that strong in bubble sort, so can't help you out, unf